# Missing elevation in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to estimate the elevation at given point. Since the estimation has to happen in real-time, I'm willing to compromise in the resolution by having a min and max elevation returned instead. I thought that I would start by creating a dataset using Google Earth Engine by dividing the earth roughly into 10 by 5 degree chunks.

[image: chunks]

Then I iterated over each chunk and added min/max elevation to each chunk using SRTM Digital Elevation Data Version 4. What I noticed is that if the chunk contains large areas of water the min/max is missing from the result. For example the following code calculates the elevation around Norway

```
var elevation = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4').select('elevation');

var createRectangle = function(lon, lat, dLon, dLat) {
  var lon1 = ee.Number(lon).subtract(dLon / 2);
  var lat1 = ee.Number(lat).subtract(dLat / 2);
  var lon2 = ee.Number(lon).add(dLon / 2);
  var lat2 = ee.Number(lat).add(dLat / 2);
  return ee.Geometry.Rectangle([lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2]);
};

var rectangles = [];
var dLon = 10;
var dLat = 5;
for (var lon = 2; lon < 20; lon+=dLon) {
  for (var lat = 59; lat < 65; lat+=dLat) {
    rectangles.push(createRectangle(lon, lat, dLon, dLat));
  }
}

var elevationStats = ee.FeatureCollection(rectangles.map(function(rectangle) {
  var statistics = elevation.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
    geometry: rectangle,
    scale: 30000
  });

  var minElevation = ee.Number(statistics.get('elevation_min'));  
  var maxElevation = ee.Number(statistics.get('elevation_max'));
  
  return ee.Feature(rectangle, { min: minElevation, max: maxElevation });
}))

Map.addLayer(elevationStats, {color: 'red'}, 'Elevation');
```

[image: around norway]

The 2 top most rectangles west coast of Norway have no elevation data where the bottom ones do. I figure that the SRTM90 does not have elevation for "ocean" but all of the chunks contain some land.

Am I using the Reducer wrong?

Edit 1:
I just noticed that the SRTM Digital Elevation Data Version 4 does not contain data above latitude 15... "high-quality elevation data at near global scope" indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the data source SRTM Digital Elevation Data Version 4 does not contain data above latitude 15.

[image]

If switched to GTOPO30: Global 30 Arc-Second Elevation all is fine

[image]